# Best way to store large forms fields in a database table

Tags: mysql, database

im recently working with a medical form that has a huge amount of fields. input, textarea, checkbox, select. etc. The problem is that i consider not efficiently to store every single one in table with an specific column for each one. what alternatives could you suggest me?

Comment: you can use a json data type in the database, I will prefer have all the columns, but since you are looking for an alternative, that is one.

Comment: Part of this depends on how you are going to use this data. Do you want to search it by individual fields? Perform groupings or summarizations? Also, especially since this is medical, do you need to encrypt certain fields, and/or limit access? A traditional RDMS has these features built-in if you use individual fields. You could instead look at alternatives that store things unstructured, but you might have to build your own system to perform these tasks. There really isn't a right or wrong for this, at least with the amount of information that you've provided so far.

Comment: If you're storing it in a schema-free database or JSON, you better use something like JSON-Schema to validate

Comment: @ChrisHaas, actually i'm only going to save and retrieve data into fields, no need to search or sumarize at all, But since this is a medical form, each doctor from another area would eventually have a different form added with different fields.

Comment: i think  what @Vidal says is a good point, no need to extra columns, everything is saved with a key and no need to worry about new fields in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like vidal said you can use json or save as array but better way is you make a 1 table for main vars like :

> ID=01 Name=Medical1

then make a meta table like :

> meta_ID=01 med_ID=01 meta_Name=price meta_value=1000

then make a meta relation table like :

> rel_ID=01 med_ID=01 meta_ID=01

then you can easily store or access your values.